# iOS11 Crash in NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds

Tags: crash, ios11, foundation

Our App Find a Foundation crash, only in iOS11. How to solve it ?

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds

0  CoreFoundation                 0x184f8bd38 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1844a0528 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x184f8bc80 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  Foundation                     0x18587c168 -[NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:]
4  Foundation                     0x18588262c -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:]
5  CoreFoundation                 0x184e65bec -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]
6  UIKit                          0x18ec677b8 -[UILayoutManagerBasedDraggableGeometry draggableObjectsForTextRange:]
```

Comment: Put some code of replacement object action in NSMutableArray.

Comment: Thank you . But we don't know what code trigger this crash . Our code use replaceObjectAtIndex so many place.

Comment: In XCode go to "Debug menu" then Move cursor on "Breakpoint" option. In which click on "Create Exception Breaskpoint". Then run again and follow same step that causes you crash. It will stuck at line where crash happen.

Comment: We find this crash from Fabric Website. It collect our crash info from our App. We can not reproduce this crash by our testing.

Comment: I am having same issue, any update please?

Comment: Seeing the same crash when dragging a link in UITextView.

Answer (score 3):

I could reproduce it in iOS 13.0 beta 4 with a sample app showing a UITextView with a special attributed string including a link. It crashes when tap-holding or dragging the link.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *aString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];

NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attachment.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"weblink"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
attachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15);
[aString appendAttributedString:[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment]];

[aString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"  More Information"]];
[aString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.apple.com"] range:NSMakeRange(0, aString.length)];

self.textView.attributedText = aString;
```

Filed on  Feedback Assistant as FB6738178.

Comment: No, please file a bug, too. It's still open as of iOS 13.2 beta 4.

Comment: Still a bug at least in iOS 12.4-14.5. Removing the attachment from the link (so, not calling `addAttribute:value:range:`) prevents the long press crash

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when use the method of UITextInput

> replaceRange:(UITextRange *)range withText:(NSString *)text;

I cannot find the best solution, but I fix the crash by avoiding using special characters

> '

in the 2nd parameter of replaceRange method

ps:the issue only occurred in iOS 11